# Deleting a pointer to an automatic variable

Tags: c++, runtime-error, undefined-behavior, delete-operator, memory-corruption

Please look at this code

```
int i = 10;                                     //line 1 
int *p = &i;                                    //line 2  
delete p;                                       //line 3 
cout << "*p = " << *p << ", i = " << i << endl; //line 4  
i = 20;                                         //line 5  
cout << "*p = " << *p << ", i = " << i << endl; //line 6  
*p = 30;                                        //line 7
cout << "*p = " << *p << ", i = " << i << endl; //line 8
```

What is the result of this code? Especially of line 3, 5 and 7? Do they invoke undefined behavior? What would be the output?

EDIT : I tried running it using g++, and it's compiling and running  fine! I'm using MinGW on Windows 7.

**What does Standard say in this context?**

Comment: have you tried running it? may be you can add the result of your run and we can discuss it then?

Comment: Why not compile it and see?  I get a segfault...

Comment: `*** error for object 0x7fff5fbff5ec: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug` while running it... compiled with g++ 4.1 in MacOS X. By my definition of "running" it is not running fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can delete only a pointer if you have ever allocated it dynamically using new. In this case you have not allocated the pointer using new but simply defined and initialized it to point to a local variable of type int.

Invoking delete on a pointer not allocated dynamically using new is something called [Undefined Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior). In short, it means that anything on the earth can happen when such a code is executed and you can't complaint a bit to anyone on this planet.

Comment: Not only should memory be allocated dynamically, it should be allocated with `new` only.

Answer (score 1):

`delete p;` is UB and so any further behavior can't be predicted or relied upon. You program might crash immediately or spend all your money or just exit from `main()` and pretend nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

Line 3 is definitely undefined behaviour, since you're trying to deleting memory at an address that is not on the heap.

Comment: why has this been downvoted, since it says the same as the one that has been upvoted?